# How to get the active language in WordPress Polylang

Tags: php, wordpress, polylang

I have setup Polylang on my WP and created pages for those 2 different languages (EN, GR).
But I want to override a plugin and present some strings in greek if the selected Frontpage language is in Greek.
I have tested with get_locale() and and get_bloginfo('language'), but both of them return the locale of the Administrator side which is en_US.

I have also tried with $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] of PHP_INFO, because when in EN the address bar contain the /en/ part, but I don't get the correct addres, rather a json request address created for the current request.

How I can get the frontend user language?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have finally succeeded to get the current language with

```
isset($_COOKIE['pll_language']) ? $_COOKIE['pll_language'] : false;
```

and it returns "en" or "el" depending the active language.

Answer (score 0):

They provide a function for that : `pll_current_language()`.

See their [documentation](https://polylang.pro/doc/function-reference/)

Comment: I know, but in my case it didn't returned anything.